# Adding a hidden Form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have been toying with this all afternoon, and not sure what is wrong. I am new to js, and not sure where I went wrong. I have tried a few solutions, and none are working. I tested the js in jfiddle, and it was working, but I can't get it to work in any other place.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/***********************************************
* Required field(s) validation v1.10- By NavSurf
* Visit Nav Surf at http://navsurf.com
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

function formCheck(formobj){
    // Enter name of mandatory fields
    var fieldRequired = Array("name", "Address", "city", "state", "zip", "phone", "email", "tradeShow");
    // Enter field description to appear in the dialog box
    var fieldDescription = Array("name", "Address", "city", "state", "zip", "phone", "email", "tradeShow");
    // dialog message
    var alertMsg = "Please complete the following fields:\n";

    var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++){
        var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
        if (obj){
            switch(obj.type){
            case "select-one":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == ""){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "select-multiple":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "text":
            case "textarea":
                if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            default:
            }
            if (obj.type == undefined){
                var blnchecked = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
                    if (obj[j].checked){
                        blnchecked = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!blnchecked){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(alertMsg);
        return false;
    }
}
// -->
</script>

<form action="submit.asp" id="qrCodeForm" method="post" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
    <!-- Display Name -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Name:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><input type="text" id="name" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display CompanyName -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Company Name:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><input type="text" id="companyName" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display Address -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Your Address:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 si-qr-address">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" id="address" runat="server"   class="col-xs-12" placeholder="Address" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" id="city" runat="server"       class="col-xs-12" placeholder="City" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <select class="colors_text col-xs-12" name="state">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="AK">AK</option>
                    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                    <option value="AR">AR</option>
                    <option value="CA">CA</option>
                    <option value="CO">CO</option>
                    <option value="CT">CT</option>
                    <option value="DE">DE</option>
                    <option value="DC">DC</option>
                    <option value="FL">FL</option>
                    <option value="GA">GA</option>
                    <option value="HI">HI</option>
                    <option value="ID">ID</option>
                    <option value="IL">IL</option>
                    <option value="IN">IN</option>
                    <option value="IA">IA</option>
                    <option value="KS">KS</option>
                    <option value="KY">KY</option>
                    <option value="LA">LA</option>
                    <option value="ME">ME</option>
                    <option value="MD">MD</option>
                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                    <option value="MI">MI</option>
                    <option value="MN">MN</option>
                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    <option value="MO">MO</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                    <option value="NE">NE</option>
                    <option value="NV">NV</option>
                    <option value="NH">NH</option>
                    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                    <option value="NM">NM</option>
                    <option value="NY">NY</option>
                    <option value="NC">NC</option>
                    <option value="ND">ND</option>
                    <option value="OH">OH</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                    <option value="RI">RI</option>
                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                    <option value="SD">SD</option>
                    <option value="TN">TN</option>
                    <option value="TX">TX</option>
                    <option value="UT">UT</option>
                    <option value="VT">VT</option>
                    <option value="VA">VA</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                    <option value="WV">WV</option>
                    <option value="WI">WI</option>
                    <option value="WY">WY</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" id="zip" runat="server"        class="col-xs-12" placeholder="Zip Code" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display Phone -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Phone Number:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><input type="text" id="phone" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display Email -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Email:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><input type="text" id="email" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display TradeShow -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">How did you find us?</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><input type="text" id="tradeShow" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>

<script language="javascript">
    function addInput(val) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'QR Code URL');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input.setAttribute('value', val);
        document.body.appendChild(input);

        //document.write("<input type='hidden' name='QR Code URL3' id='qrCodeUrl3' value=" + window.location.pathname + ">");
        //document.write(window.location.pathname);
        document.write("<input type='hidden' name='QR Code URL3' id='qrCodeUrl3' value=" + val + ">");
        alert("PATH URL:" + val);
    }

    window.load function {
        document.write("<input type='hidden' name='QR Code URL3' id='qrCodeUrl3' value=" + val + ">");
    }

    addInput(window.location.pathname);

    //  $('<input>').attr({
    //      type: 'hidden',
    //      id: 'foo',
    //      name: 'bar', 
    //      value: window.location.pathname
    //  }).appendTo('form');



    //  $('#qrCodeForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="qrCodeUrl4" value="' + window.location.pathname + '" />');


    //'QrUrl.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
</script>
<!-- Qr Code Stuff -->
<input name="QR Code URL2" id="QrUrl2" value="<asp print path; />" type="hidden">

    <!-- Display CAPTCHA -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><img class="captcha" ></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><input name="Verification_Code" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Display Submit -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><input type="submit" value="Submit for Coupon Code" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-xs-12" alt="Submit for Coupon Code"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The final site will be running bootstrap. All I am trying to get working is the creation of a hidden input with the current url, without domain, as the value.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: There is no language attribute for script elements, and HTML comment delimiters within the element have not been required for decades, if ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append the hidden element to your `<form>` element, you can reference it by passing it's  `id` attribute to the [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) function and using the [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) function as you previously were :

```
function addInput(val) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'QR Code URL');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    input.setAttribute('value', val);
    // Append this element to the form
    document.getElementById('qrCodeForm').appendChild(input);  
}
```

And simply call this at the end of your `<script>` tag :

```
addInput(window.location.pathname);
```

You can [see a working example / fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/yuvubu/edit?html,output) :

[image]

Comment: "*… you can reference it by it's id…*" No, don't do that. Use `document.getElementById('qrCodeForm')` or `document.forms('qrCodeForm')` or similar..

Comment: I've updated the example. I suppose I was feeling adventurous to use the `id` approach, as I almost exclusively use the `getElementById()` function.

Comment: Creating named properties of window for each element with an ID was an IE invention around version 4. It was never considered a good idea, other browsers copied it for compatibility when IE had 95% user share. It persists.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to post so much code, consider [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In your code you have:

```
    document.body.appendChild(input);
```

which will append the input to the document but not associate it with the form. You can either set the input's *form* attribute to the form ID, or you can append it as a child of the form, so either:

```
input.setAttribute('form', 'qrCodeForm');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('qrCodeForm').appendChild(input);
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#qrCodeForm').appendChild(input);
```

or similar.

Also you have:

```
    document.write("<input type='hidden' name='QR Code URL3' id='qrCodeUrl3' value=" + val + ">");
    alert("PATH URL:" + val);
```

Calling *document.write* after the page has loaded will call *document.open*, which will clear the **entire** content of the document (head and body) and replace it with what you pass, so the document will consist of just the hidden input element. Don't add elements to the page this way.